# How to know whether detached std::thread has finished its execution?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I have a function like following in which threads acquire a lock by using std::lock_guard mutex and write to the file via ofstream.

When the current file size increases the max size, then I create an independent thread that compresses the file and should terminate.

If the log file is big in size (say ~500MB), it takes around 25+ seconds to compress.
I detach the compress thread since no other thread (or main) wants to wait for this thread to finish.

But I need to know that the compress thread is not running before the execution of following line:

```
_compress_thread(compress_log, _logfile).detach();
```

Sample code snippet:

```
    void log (std::string message)
    {
        // Lock using mutex
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

        _outputFile << message << std::endl;
        _outputFile.flush();
        _sequence_number++;
        _curr_file_size = _outputFile.tellp();

        if (_curr_file_size >= max_size) {
            // Code to close the file stream, rename the file, and reopen
            ...


            // Create an independent thread to compress the file since
            // it takes some time to compress huge files.
            if (the_compress_thread_is_not_already_running) //pseudo code
            {
                _compress_thread(compress_log, _logfile).detach();
            }
        }
    }
```

In the above `if` condition i.e. `the_compress_thread_is_not_already_running`, how can I be sure that the compress thread is not running?

```
void * compress_log (std::string s) 
{

    // Compress the file
    // ...

}
```

Comment: Set a flag before creating the thread, have the thread clear it right before terminating.

Comment: If you need to know if a thread is still running then it doesn't sound like you actually want to `detach`. `detach` is often a sign of a problem with the design. The statement *"I need to know that the compress thread is not running"* implies that there should be 1 compression thread which is contrary to using `detach` and contrary to the statement *"no other thread (or main) wants to wait for this thread to finish"*.

Comment: You could also use `std::async` and keep a future object.  Then you could use that to make sure sure the previous call has ended before you call it again.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I thought of that, but thinking what if the compress thread's clean up is in progress (after (un)/setting the flag, and the other thread ends up executing `std::thread _compress_thread(compress_log, _logfile).detach();`

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: I'm not very sure, but I was under the impression that it may create UB because `std::thread _compress_thread` is common for the new and old thread?

Comment: `std::thread _compress_thread(compress_log, _logfile);` is a local variable, local to your function and always makes a new object. It never refers to an existing thread.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Actually, for this question I have written it like it looks local to the function. In original code, `std::thread _compress_thread` is a class member variable...

Comment: @C_user5 Then `detach` is the exact opposite of what you want to do. `join` with it before you assign a new value to it. `detach` means "I don't care about this thread, when it finishes or even if it finishes" which is not true in your case. Edit : But as the comments and answers have pointed out, you would be better off with a `std::async` and storing a `std::future` instead. `std::thread` is intended to be used as a low level fundamental object. It's not designed to be easy to use. If you want to run a task asynchronously (compress a file) use `std::async`. It's what it's for.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Sure, thanks. I will explore `std::async`

Comment: Do you really want to be compressing a log file while writing to its tail? Might it not be a better idea to open a new log file and launch a thread to compress the old one in the background?

Comment: @RichardHodges, In the original code, I'm already doing following stuffs: "close the file stream, rename the file, and reopen while I hold the lock so that other threads may keep logging into a fresh file ". Removed them from the code snippet for readability.

Will mention this in the question.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to detect whether a detached thread of execution has terminated.

If you for some reason need to guarantee that at most one thread is compressing simultaneously, then a simple solution is to use `std::async`. It returns a *future* object. You can query the future object whether the associated callback has finished. Same effect can be achieved in a less strucuted way using a detached thread by modifying a shared variable at the end of the function (note that shared access must be synchronised).

Another approach could be to constantly keep alive a compression thread, but block it as long as there is no work to be done. The thread can be notified using a condition variable to start its work and once finished, resume blocking until next notification.

P.S. You might want to first close the file stream, rename the file, and reopen while you hold the lock so that other threads may keep logging into a fresh file while the previous logs - now in the renamed file - are being compressed.

Comment: Thanks. In the original code, I'm already doing following stuffs: "close the file stream, rename the file, and reopen".

Removed them from the code snippet for readability.

Comment: For the approach "using a detached thread by modifying a shared variable at the end of the function (note that shared access must be synchronised)", suppose I use a shared variable and guard it using the same mutex i.e. `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx)`, still there is a possibility that the compress thread's clean up is in progress (after modifying the shared variable), and the other thread ends up executing `_compress_thread(compress_log, _logfile).detach();` . Isn't it..

Comment: @C_user5 I wouldn't use the same mutex. I would recommend using atomic variable instead. That said, I don't recommend that approach in the first place, since `std::async` is simpler. `still there is a possibility that the compress thread's clean up is in progress` sure. Same applies to using `std::async`. If that's a problem for you, then perhaps the constant compression thread approach is good for you. That said, I can't see why it would be a problem.